# Scraping Oracle text-file using pcre in php

Tags: php, regex, screen-scraping, pcre

I would like to scrape a text-file which is the output from Oracle AP. I don't have access to Oracle, but need to assist in bug hunting and compare text-file against two csv-files from other systems. Importing the csv-files into a database is not a problem, but I'm struggling with this text-file.

The text-file is divided in two parts. What is successfully imported, and what is rejected. Each column has a specific width set by Oracle when creating the report. They will not change the setting for column width. If content of a column exceeds the width it simply continues on the row below. And columns for imported and rejected are not 100% the same.

For the successful imports it's simple, as there is one version of every row, but the rejected one might have more than one row for different reasons.

The import file is shortened and obfuscated for obvious reasons, as it can be several thousands of lines. It's best viewed in a text editor without word-wrap. I cannot get it to look any good in this forum with blockquote or code sample  in forum editor, so please view/copy it from links below.

I'm showing the successful ones on regex101.com [here](https://regex101.com/r/XqNWk7/1).

Regex finding the imported (I'm sure it could be better, but it works and that is good enough for me):

```
\s(\d+)\s+([\D]{2,})(\d+)\s+(\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{2})\s+(\w+)\s+([\w+\,]*\.\d+)\s+(\d)\s+([\w+\,]*\.\d+)\s+(\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{2})
```

I'm struggling with the rejected ones however, due to the variations.

- Duplicate invoice number, if there are more than one reason (column) for not being imported.
- Missing supplier number and supplier name (always shows up in pair).

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/381srn/2) is what I'm done so far with the rejected ones.

Regex finding rejected:

```
^\s(\d+)\s+([\D]{2,})(\d+)\s+(\d{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-\d{2})\s+(\w+)\s+(-?[\w]{1,}\.?\d+)\s+
```

Clearly my regex for rejected is not the final result. It's crap at the moment. It would even scrape a successful row.

My questions:

- Is it possible to have only one regex for rejected catching the variations mentioned in bullet points above? Example would be appreciated.
- Is it possible to fetch the word-wrapped parts of a column? Example would be appreciated.

I'm trying to understand the PCRE documentation regarding conditionals as it might be of help when dealing with the rejected variations, but so far I'm struggling with it.

Regards,

Bjørn

Comment: I think using a regex in this case isn't the good approach. Read your file line by line, use the fixed width to extract informations and write a generator function to rebuild fields that spread over several lines.

Comment: Casimir et Hippolyte, thanks for your input. Will look into your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, you might want to use unpack for things like this